# Vue 3 vite ignore errors during build

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, eslint, vite

I am getting the error "TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."

I wanted to just disable this rather than fix it in the code.
I am using "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build" for my build in package.json

Currently running vue 3 / vite with latest in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out my code it turns out most things were severely outdated in package.json.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to fix the code for some reason, you could suppress the error with a preceding comment, containing [`@ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments):

```js
// @ts-expect-error
const s: string = 123
```

Or [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```js
// @ts-ignore
const s: string = 123
```

From [`@ts-ignore` or `@ts-expect-error`?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#ts-ignore-or-ts-expect-error):

> Pick `ts-expect-error` if:
>
> - you’re writing test code where you actually want the type system to error on an operation
> - you expect a fix to be coming in fairly quickly and you just need a quick workaround
> - you’re in a reasonably-sized project with a proactive team that wants to remove suppression comments as soon affected code is valid again
>
> Pick `ts-ignore` if:
>
> - you have a larger project and new errors have appeared in code with no clear owner
> - you are in the middle of an upgrade between two different versions of TypeScript, and a line of code errors in one version but not another.
> - you honestly don’t have the time to decide which of these options is better.

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/mLqOkW)